# Skipping specific rows while reading an excel file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Objective is to load 'Energy Indicators.xls' file using pandas.
I need to skip a single specific row while reading the sheet. How can it be done?

I have skipped the first 16 rows, after which i require the 17th row, but the 18th row has to be skipped and the remaining after row no. 18 are needed:

```py
import pandas as pd
energy= pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', header= [0,1], index_col= 0, skiprows= 16, usecols= "C:F", skipfooter= 38, 
                      na_values= "...")
energy
```

So, how do i skip the 18th row?

Comment: how about reading the whole excel file then drop row number 18? try this `df.drop(18, axis=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using the pd.read_excel attributes to obtain the motive, and avoiding drop() and got the result using this:

```
import pandas as pd
skipr= list(range(0,16))
skipr.append(17)
energy= pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls', skiprows= skipr, usecols= "C:F", skipfooter= 38, na_values= "...")
```

Thanks, for those who answered earlier!

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the row after reading the whole file

```
dataframe.drop(17, axis=0)
```